# running linux command txl from java program

Tags: java, shell, command-line

I know we can run a linux terminal command in a java program like following code shows a "ls" command for the home directory.

```
String[] cmd1 =  {
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "cd ../.. && ls"};
        Process child1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
        child1.waitFor();

final BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child1.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println("output is: "+line);
        }
```

But I have no idea what "/bin/sh" and "-c" mean for? I searched it online and somebody used "bash" or else. And if I run the command as "cd ../.. && ls" only, I will get the same result.

So if there is a command in terminal as "txl -o output inputFile", where "txl" is a tool installed, how to write in in java? I tried

```
String[] cmd1 =  {
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "cd ../.. && txl -o output inputFile"};
```

But could not get the result. I add "cd ../.." to go to the home directory first from the working space because txl is installed in the home bin directory.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

EDIT:

I made a stupid spelling error and the command in this format works!

Comment: I would, personally, avoid using `Runtime.exec` directly and instead use `ProcessBuilder`. Having said that, you `cmd` array should be split so that each element represents an individual parameter that would sent to the command your are executing.  You example would suggest that `cd ../.. && ls` will appear as a single argument to the command you are executing, which isn't what you want

Comment: Thanks, madprogrammer. If so, which way is correct to write cmd1 `String [] cmd1 = {"/bin/sh",
        "-c","cd ../..", "txl -o output inputFile"}` or `String [] cmd1 = {"cd ../..", "txl -o output inputFile"}`? Or could you tell me how to write cmd1? Thanks! @MadProgrammer

Comment: I would suggest something more like `{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd", "../..", "&&", "txl", "-o", "output", "inputFile"}` but you may need to experiment with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is a program, this is the shell, the option `-c` specifies that the following is a command to be executed by the shell (which is the third "line" of your cmd1: `cd ../.. && ls`)

EDIT:

In this case is nessesary to execute the shell, executing only `cd ../.. && ls` won't work, because operators like the `&&` between `cd` and `ls` are not understood by Java but by the shell.

Comment: Thanks, morgano. If so, it should work for command "cd ../.. && txl -o output inputFile" right? Or the java program can only run some default commands like ls, cd, dir etc? @morgano

Comment: @Eve I fixed my answer, actually you won't get the same result if you try to execute only cd ../.. && ls

Answer (score 0):

you can find [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ls.htm) what every parameter in ls do:

```
-c
 with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information) with -l: show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by ctime
```

in order to execute a program in java and wait for it to finish you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444812/executing-a-command-from-java-and-waiting-for-the-command-to-finish) post