# Execute .bat file from java and wait till its finished

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have gone through few questions raised on how to achieve this.
I used `process.waitFor()` and `/wait` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444812/executing-a-command-from-java-and-waiting-for-the-command-to-finish?rq=1). The problem is by doing so it waits not just till the command is executed but until cmd prompt is closed (can be done by adding `exit` in the bat file). But I cannot modify bat file as its a Product file.

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        String path = "C:/Folder/c.bat";
        String executeCmd= "cmd /c start /wait "+path;
        final Process process =run.exec(executeCmd);        
        process.waitFor();
         System.out.println("did I wait?");
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How to make it wait only till the command is executed.

Comment: Take out `start /wait`? (It looks like you're already waiting for cmd.exe to close.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart if I remove `start`  , it doesn't get executed , if I remove `wait` . it doesn't even wait and prints _did I wait?_

Comment: Then it depends on what `C:/Folder/c.bat` is doing. If it is launching an executable asynchronously, then you won't be able to wait for that executable to terminate without finding out its process ID and then waiting for it to close.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Your point is valid,Suppose if I go with the above logic that I mentioned.Is there anyway I can check if the prompt is back and if so I can proceed.In my case bat file is stopping and starting application server

Comment: To do what you suggest would be a very awkward and brittle solution. A much better solution is to find the executable's process ID and wait for it to close.

Comment: How can I find the PID and wait for it ?

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but presumably there are some classes available. I would ask a new question with your specific goal in mind. For example: "I am launching a shell script (batch file) from a Java program, and the shell script I am running launches an executable. How can I wait for that executable to terminate before continuing in my program?"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper batch file with following content:

```
start /wait %1\c.bat
exit
```

Store this helper batch anywhere you want to.

Then start this helper batch file with the path to `c.bat` as its parameter.

```
   Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
      String pathToCBatch = "C:\\Folder\\"; 
      String pathToHelperBatch = "c:/helperBatch.bat";
      String executeCmd = "cmd /c start /wait " + pathToHelperBatch + " " + pathToCBatch;
      final Process process = run.exec(executeCmd);
      System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
      process.waitFor();
      System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Its not working as expected,waits for the command prompt to close .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve then? Should the program wait or not?

Comment: the .bat file is used to start server, I want the code to wait till it starts. The logic you have written will wait until the cmd promt is closed manually , I tried it

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same issue: "call a Batch file and wait until it's finished" (*Windows PC*). This solution works for me :

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("cmd /c start /wait C:\\script.bat");
    // my script take 2 file as arguments
    command.append(" ").append(inputFile);
    command.append(" ").append(outputFile);
    try {
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dont work for me to exit cmd from java
i have come with a solution
i added "exit" in my .bat file at the end and it works now

example :
this is my "adservice.google.com.bat" bat file which dont exit after executing from java

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="adservice.google.com.bat"  protocol=any dir=out action=block remoteip=2404:6800:4009:80f::2002,216.58.203.34
```

so i have to add "exit" in it , in the last line

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="adservice.google.com.bat"  protocol=any dir=out action=block remoteip=2404:6800:4009:80f::2002,216.58.203.34
exit
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

also if the directory has space in it then the command wont work from string of arrey

so instead do this

```
File file = new File("E:\\NetBeans Projects\\Test.bat");

String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start",  file.getName() };
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(command , null , file.getParentFile());
```